# Regex expression: number of characters containing a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

| Desc_ORF | ORF |
| --- | --- |
| beta-glucosidase | tb512 |
| succinate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase | tb111 |
| probable epoxide hydrolase | tb045 |

I am using this function to filter the dataframe:

```
df.set_index('Desc_ORF').filter(regex=pattern, axis=0)
```

It is working perfectly fine with other patterns that I'am trying, but I cannot obtain a regex pattern that filters the rows where the Desc_ORF contains **hydro** into a word of 13 characters.

For example: My code should keep the row *succinate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase* because it contains *dehydrogenase* that has 13 characters and contains the pattern **hydro**. On the other hand, the filter must discard *probable epoxide hydrolase* because, although it contains **hydro**, the word hydrolase is not of 13 characters.

| Desc_ORF | ORF |
| --- | --- |
| succinate-semialdehyde dehydrogenase | tb111 |

I have tried different patterns and my last try has been: ^(?={13}$)(\b\S*hydro\S*\b). With this  pattern I am only filtering by words that contain hydro, but I cannot obtain words that contain hydro with a length of 13 characters.

Comment: The "ex" in "regex" already means "expression"; the term is short for *regular expression.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to match the word in the second line could be:

```
(?<!\S)(?=\S{13}(?!\S))\S*hydro\S*
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace bounadary on the left
- `(?=\S{13}(?!\S))` Assert 13 non whitespace chars followed by a whitespace boundary
- `\S*hydro\S*` Match hydro between optional non whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/67zmsC/1)

```
pattern=r"(?<!\S)(?=\S{13}(?!\S))\S*hydro\S*"
df = df.set_index('Desc_ORF').filter(regex=pattern, axis=0)
```